# Multiple Instances New Class() C#

Tags: c#

What I've noticed, is using

Program.cs has

```
public static List<Client> clients = new List<Client>();
```

the Button

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
                         Client client = new Client(combobox1.selecteditem);
                         Program.clients.Add(client);
         }
```

Client.cs
All variables are non-static public. But there is an eventhandler where on packetrecv, a class is called, this class is then filtered and processes

Where it is called is

```
public void recieved(short op, string str, Client c)
        {
switch (op)
                {
case (short)OpCodes.matches:
                        {
                            c.something(c, str);
                            break;
                        }
}
}
```

Handler.cs

```
 public void something(Client c, string movement)
           {
                 if (movement == null)
                 c.coords = movement;
                 c.freeSpot = true;
             }
```

And in the above ^ the variables would overlap and freespotwould be made true throughout all the instances

will work find with one instance. But I'm trying to compile with multiple instances.
So creating a `button_onclick` would create a new instance using the above.

As the program is running, it runs flawlessly on one instance, but with 2+ instances, the variables in `MyClass` start to overlap. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: Do you mean that you only created one object and two variables are sharing the same instance of the object? If you don't then I am not certain what you mean.

Comment: Your `MyClass` variables are `static` when they should not be.

Comment: You will have to post more code (at least button_onclick) for us to understand exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: no, none of my variables are static

Comment: Well, please post the minimum amount of code that demonstrates your problem then, otherwise we are guessing.

Comment: button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
MyClass name = new MyClass();
-defines variables here-
name.LoginID = loginID.TextBox;
......
}





Public partial class MyClass
{
 public string LoginID;
}

Comment: If you need to create a new instance on every button click, you should set up a `List<MyClass>` and collect the instances there

Comment: I already have that:


public static List<Client> clients = new List<Client>();
Program.clients.Add(client);

Could eventhandlers be jumping classes? o_O

Comment: Edit your question and put the code there please, it's hard to read code in comments

Comment: Try -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3992921/how-to-share-an-instance-of-a-class-with-many-classes

Comment: If `freeSpot` is not static, `something` must be being called for all client instances.. can you post the code where `something` is called?

Comment: It is called at the same time for all client instances. Could that be the problem? Is there a way to like, prevent it from colliding and keep the instances separate?

Comment: Please don't create duplicate questions http://stackoverflow.com/q/16271531/81053

Comment: Can you post the code that calls recieved?  That's the place where the Client object is determined, and hence seems to be the likely culprit.

Comment: i need to have clarification, do mean the problem is occur when multiple client instances is added in (List<client>)clients field or when multiple instance of "program.cs" e.g open same exe file twice or more?