# Multiple Instances, Trouble with overlapping variables C#

Tags: c#

I am using the code sample below -

Program.cs has a list of clients as:

```
public static List<Client> clients = new List<Client>();
```

with an event handler for click on button1

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     Client client = new Client(combobox1.selecteditem);
     Program.clients.Add(client);
 }
```

Client.cs

All variables are non-static and public. There is an eventhandler where on packet receive, a class is called, this class is then filtered and processed

it is called in the following code:

```
public void recieved(short op, string str, Client c)
{
    switch (op)
    {
        case (short)OpCodes.matches:
        {
            c.something(c, str);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Handler.cs

```
public void something(Client c, string movement)
{
    if (movement == null)
        c.coords = movement;
    c.freeSpot = true;
}
```

And in the above ^ the variables would overlap and freespot would be made true throughout all the instances.

It will work fine with one instance. But I'm trying to compile with multiple instances.
So creating a `button_onclick` would create a new instance using the above.

As the program is running, it runs flawlessly on one instance, but with 2+ instances, the variables in `MyClass` start to overlap. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: If you are using visual studio, try using its wonderful debugger and tracking all the difference instances of Client by giving them, for example, a uniquely generated ID

Comment: What does the code look like that calls `recieved(...)`?

Comment: the code that calls recieved(...) is an eventhandler

Comment: @user2309449 Please don't ask the same question more than once http://stackoverflow.com/q/16271080/81053

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for certain without more context, but this may be a concurrency problem.  List is not thread safe.  Try using `ConcurrentBag<T>` instead of `List<T>`.